# Finding change over time from a table in R - fitting a model to the data

Tags: r

[this is the table that has the information, it is much larger but I have just included a small part of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uj1RT.png)

Part 1 : (solved) This might seem quite easy, but I am very stuck on creating code to make a graph which shows the change over time. The table shows infant mortality and I just need a graph showing how the infant mortality of one country has changed over time.

Part 2 : how can I fit a line to the data - for example, for just one country? I need to model the data as a linear response. How can I do this?

```
my_data <- structure(list(`1800` = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", 
"Andorra", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", 
"Australia", "Austria"), `1801` = c(469L, 375L, 460L, NA, 486L, 
474L, 402L, 371L, 391L, 387L), `1802` = c(469L, 375L, 460L, NA, 
486L, 470L, 402L, 371L, 391L, 373L), `1803` = c(469L, 375L, 460L, 
NA, 486L, 466L, 402L, 370L, 391L, 359L), `1804` = c(469L, 375L, 
460L, NA, 486L, 462L, 402L, 370L, 391L, 346L), `1805` = c(469L, 
375L, 460L, NA, 486L, 458L, 402L, 369L, 391L, 333L), `1806` = c(469L, 
375L, 460L, NA, 486L, 455L, 402L, 369L, 391L, 321L), `1807` = c(470L, 
375L, 460L, NA, 486L, 451L, 402L, 368L, 391L, 309L), `1808` = c(470L, 
375L, 460L, NA, 486L, 447L, 402L, 368L, 391L, 325L), `1809` = c(470L, 
375L, 460L, NA, 486L, 444L, 402L, 367L, 391L, 316L)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please use `dput` to show a small reproducible example

Comment: did that work - I tried to add a reproducible example

Comment: Perhaps you need a `matplot` `matplot(t('row.names<-'(as.matrix(my_data[-1]), my_data[[1]])), type = 'l')`

Comment: what exactly does that show? I'm confused

Comment: What is the time variable? The columns' names are 1800, 1801, ..., 1809. The data doesn't seem to have a time variable.

Comment: Those are years, I don't know exactly how to add a time variable but there are new values every year etc

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question

Answer (score 0):

You can plot what the question asks for with package `ggplot2`.
This type of problems generaly has to do with reshaping the data. The format should be the long format and the data is in wide format. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) on how to reshape the data from long to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

my_data %>% 
  rename(country = `1800`) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with('18'),
    names_to = 'time',
    values_to = 'mortality'
  ) %>%
  mutate(time = as.numeric(time)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(time, mortality, color = country)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: it keeps saying that it cannot find function pivot_longer - is there a reason for this? Thanks for your help

Comment: @000elizah000 `pivot_longer` is a new function in package `tidyr`, introduced in version `1.0.0`. See what `packageVersion('tidyr')` gives, maybe it's time to update.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `matplot` from `base R`

```
matplot(t('row.names<-'(as.matrix(my_data[-1]), my_data[[1]])), 
          type = 'l', xaxt = 'n')
legend("top", my_data[[1]], col = seq_along(my_data[[1]]),
          fill = seq_along(my_data[[1]]))
```